# Checking out SVN repository through web page

Tags: svn, repository

I have a repository where I keep all my homemade code, and I was thinking in sharing some of my projects. The question is I don't want to share the full path to my repository, but instead create some links in my website to act as "pointers". Example:

Repository Structure:

```
repository/
     projectA/
        /trunk
        /branches
        /tags
           /1.0
```

And my objective is to checkout like:

svn co http://some.address/myproject/1.0

Is it possible?

Note: Of course my webpage and svn repository are hosted in the same place.

Comment: I tried to implement a similar solution a year back using mod rewrite but failed hard on the authentication part. Digest and rewrites didn't mix well. And of course there could problems with having 2 access points to one resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using svn in combination with webdav?
You can create permissions for subfolders. For example bob is only able to read `tags/1.0/` while alice can read and write to `trunk/`:

```
[projectA:/tags/1.0/]
      bob = r

[projectA:/trunk/]
      alice = rw
```